# get the class from input file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing a contact book and I'm stuck with a problem.

***Code***:

```
<label for="file">A picture </label><br>
<label for="file">Another picture </label>

<input type="file" id="file" class="1"/>
<input type="file" id="file" class="2"/>

$('input:file').change(function(){
alert(this.className)
})
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/0gq79qtx/1/)

***My Problem***: I can't get the class name from each element. When the second element is clicked, the first elements' classname is showed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

IDs of HTML elements should be unique (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp). <strike>Therefore jQuery can't distinguish between your elements which both have the id "file".</strike>

EDIT:

Actually my first answer was wrong, jQuery can distinguish, but both labels are allocated to the first element. [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0gq79qtx/4/)

```
<label for="file1">A picture </label><br>
<label for="file2">Another picture </label>

<input type="file" id="file1" class="1"/>
<input type="file" id="file2" class="2"/>
```

Comment: Yes, the ID's should be unique, but that doesn't actually relate to the problem here.  If you change the ID on the second input, you'll see that doesn't fix the problem.  The JQuery event is not tied by ID.  It's tied to the input type.

Comment: Works for me if I also change the content of <label for="id"> to the new id. However, you are right, it's not a problem with jQuery, but with the labels (see edit).

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the css which hides your inputs, you'll see it works just fine.  And you'll see why...  When the inputs are hidden, you're clicking on the label, not the input, and both of the labels appear BEFORE the first input.  So you are always selecting the first input and never the second one.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0gq79qtx/2/)

To fix this, either wrap the labels around the inputs, like so:

```
<label for="file">A picture <input type="file" id="file" class="1"/></label>
<br />
<label for="file2">Another picture <input type="file" id="file2" class="2"/></label>
```

or put the label for the second input just before the input, like so:

```
<label for="file">A picture </label>
<input type="file" id="file" class="1"/>
<br />
<label for="file2">Another picture </label>
<input type="file" id="file2" class="2"/>
```

NOTE:  It's not valid HTML to have multiple elements with the same ID.  In the examples above, I changed the ID on the second input to "file2"

Comment: @ArijanitNittiSalihu - find another approach?  Because non-unique ID's is invalid.  It's not the cause of your problem, but it still is invalid.  The cause of your problem is the label placement with hidden inputs.  The click event always hits the first input in that scenario.

Comment: I changed the id in my php-file. It's working but not in the way that I want to.